# Что использовать для релиза Web-приложения на Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, развертывание, непрерывная-интеграция

Пишу Web-приложение.
Api на Laravel. Фронт на Vue JS 
Есть сервер и задача:
Реализовать логику развертывания web-приложений.

Когда разработчик заканчивает работу над задачей, он сливает ветку задачи с веткой dev.

На сервере, по адресу. dev.site.ru:

1. Автоматически подгружаются последние изменения (git pull)
2. Обновляются необходимые пакеты (Composer, npm)
3. Перезапускаются контейнеры Docker

Точно такая же логика при слиянии ветки с веткой release.

Как такое можно организовать? Deployer? CI/CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите на это https://jenkins.io/

В любом случае придется писать еще скрипты, которые выполняют отдельные задачи, а дженкинс будет их выполнять по заданному воркфлоу.